# Removing duplicates by using the substring of attribute value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates, grouping

I have an XML where duplicates can be found as the last part of `<rf id>`. For example in the below sample XML, `<rf id ="cc_2_30">` and `<rf id ="cc_3_30">` are duplicated since they both have '_30' at the end.

```
<rfs>
<rf id="cc_2_30">
  <addData>
  <CC/>
    <key/>
    <recs>
      <rec/>
    </recs>
  </addData>
</rf>
<rf id="cc_3_30">
  <addData>
  <CC/>
    <key/>
    <recs>
      <rec/>
    </recs>
  </addData>
</rf>
<rf id="cc_3_13">
  <addData>
  <CC/>
    <key/>
    <recs>
      <rec/>
    </recs>
  </addData>
</rf>
</rfs>
```

So my requirement is to have only one as below

```
<rfs>
<rf id="cc_2_30">
 <addData>
 <CC/>
   <key/>
   <recs>
     <rec/>
   </recs>
 </addData>
</rf>
<rf id="cc_3_13">
 <addData>
 <CC/>
   <key/>
   <recs>
     <rec/>
   </recs>
 </addData>
</rf>
</rfs>
```

My updated XSLT after applying code to remove duplicate is -

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gal="http://www.tridan.it/gal"  version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="APOS" select='"&apos;"'/>
    
    <xsl:function name="gal:formatId">
    <xsl:param name="unformattedId"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($unformattedId, concat(' &amp;/()][*,’|\',$APOS), '_')"/>
    </xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/rfs"  exclude-result-prefixes="gal">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="rf/recs/rec/addData/entry[key='CC']" group-by="value[1]" >
            <xsl:variable name="cc1value" select="./value[1]"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//rf/recs/rec/addData/entry[key='Att']" group-by="value[1]" >
                <xsl:variable name="cc2value" select="./value[1]"/>

            
                <xsl:for-each select="//rf[recs/rec/addData[entry[key='CC' and value=$cc1value] and entry[key='Att' and value=$cc2value]]]">
                    <xsl:variable name="famId">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(./@id,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <rf id="{gal:formatId(concat($cc1value,'_',$cc2value,'_',$famId))}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="./addData"/>
                        <cc><xsl:value-of select="gal:formatId(concat($cc1value,'_',$cc2value))"/></cc> 
                        <name><xsl:value-of select="./name"/></name>
                        <recs>          
                            <xsl:for-each select="recs/rec[addData[entry[key='CC' and value=$cc1value] and entry[key='Att' and value=$cc2value]]]">
                            <xsl:variable name="recID">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(./@id,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')"></xsl:value-of>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <rec id ="{gal:formatId(concat($cc1value,'_',$cc2value,'_',$recID))}">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="./addData"/>
                            </rec>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </recs>
                    </rf>
                </xsl:for-each>
        
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/recs">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="rf"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="rf" group-by="tokenize(@id, '_')[last()]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="rf"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I am concerned now is the duplicates are removed but the `<rf id=""/>` , `<cc>` values and `<rec id=""/>` being updated which is not required. I want to retain the values that I have updated in the XSLT.

Please guide in this direction..

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? How exactly does your attempt fail?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 . The duplicates are not getting removed.

Comment: If you can use XSLT 2.0, then why are you doing Muenchian grouping instead of `xsl:for-each-group` or `distinct-values()`??

Comment: As I mentioned , my other part of XSLT is modifying <CC> value.

Comment: That is irrelevant to what I asked. (And it is also incorrect: you are copying the entire `rf` branch; once that is done, any "other part of XSLT" will have no effect on the `CC`  subbranch copied along.)

Comment: OK Let me rephrase -

Answer (score 0):

The sample has e.g. `id="cc_2_30` with two `_` so your XPath (I would use `tokenize(@id, '_')[last()]` given that you have XSLT 2) should use `substring-after` two times and not four times.

With all the edits and comments I supposed you want something along the lines of

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gal="http://www.tridan.it/gal"  version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="gal">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="APOS" select='"&apos;"'/>
    
    <xsl:function name="gal:formatId">
    <xsl:param name="unformattedId"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($unformattedId, concat(' &amp;/()][*,’|\',$APOS), '_')"/>
    </xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/rfs">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="first-step">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="rf/recs/rec/addData/entry[key='CC']" group-by="value[1]" >
            <xsl:variable name="cc1value" select="./value[1]"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//rf/recs/rec/addData/entry[key='Att']" group-by="value[1]" >
                <xsl:variable name="cc2value" select="./value[1]"/>

            
                <xsl:for-each select="//rf[recs/rec/addData[entry[key='CC' and value=$cc1value] and entry[key='Att' and value=$cc2value]]]">
                    <xsl:variable name="famId">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(./@id,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <rf id="{gal:formatId(concat($cc1value,'_',$cc2value,'_',$famId))}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="./addData"/>
                        <cc><xsl:value-of select="gal:formatId(concat($cc1value,'_',$cc2value))"/></cc> 
                        <name><xsl:value-of select="./name"/></name>
                        <recs>          
                            <xsl:for-each select="recs/rec[addData[entry[key='CC' and value=$cc1value] and entry[key='Att' and value=$cc2value]]]">
                            <xsl:variable name="recID">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(./@id,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')"></xsl:value-of>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <rec id ="{gal:formatId(concat($cc1value,'_',$cc2value,'_',$recID))}">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="./addData"/>
                            </rec>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </recs>
                    </rf>
                </xsl:for-each>
        
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
     </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$first-step/rf" group-by="tokenize(@id, '_')[last()]">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Let me rephrase - My final XML has duplicate elements  as -                                             <rf id = "cc_3_att_2_fid_3005"/> and  <rf id = "cc_3_att_2_fid_3005"/>     under <rfs>. I am using below XSLT 2.0     `<xsl:template match="/rfs">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="rf"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="rf" group-by="@id">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>   ` , But still duplicates are not removed

Comment: @user13583928, consider to edit your question and show samples there in a well-formatted way. It seems, if you want to group `rf` elements and exclude duplicates based on `for-each-group select="rf" group-by="tokenize(@id, '_')[last()]"`, then of course you shouldn't also have the `xsl:copy-of select="rf"`, as that simply copies all `rf` elements.

Comment: Added the updated XSLT. What I am now concerned is duplicates are removed but the `<rf id=""/>` , `<cc>` values and `<rec id=""/>` being updated which is not required. I want to retain the values that I have updated in the XSLT.

Comment: @user13583928, that is rather confusing, so some part of your XSLT does some update you want, some other part you randomly add makes some changes you don't want. It is not clear what you want to achieve. Perhaps run two separate transformations or clarify which changes you want, which are implemented by which part, and which changes occur you don't want, with text and samples in the question.

Comment: The sample is data is way too big so be accommodated here. What I want to do is group the data on some logic and change the <rf id>, <rec id> and <cc> values. The resulting XML have some duplicates. and I want to remove those duplicates as well. All I have to do in 1 transformation only.

Comment: Then use a variable where you store the result of the first grouping logic, then use the second grouping step to eliminate the duplicates on the variable.

Comment: I am unable to do that. Can you please guide how can I store the result of template <xsl:template match="/rfs"> and reuse it to remove duplicates.

Comment: @user13583928, I posted code on how to do that, if it fails for you then show us exactly what you have tried, based on the suggestion, and how it failed exactly.